# Do I have to register a new Bundle ID to upload new application to iTune Connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, app-id, bundle-identifier

it is my very first time to upload an application to iTune Connect, and this one freaks me out:
The selection of bundle id appears to be only one option: ***"Xcode iOS Wildcard App ID - ****", and there is a line below: you can register a new bundle id. 
The question is, do I have to register a new bundle id? if not, what will be the ***bundle id suffix***?

Thanks a lot!

p.s. I like simple things so that is why I try to avoid register something either wrong format or easily forgotten.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to register a new bundle id in the apple developer center for your new app, in the "Certificates, identifiers and profile" section:
https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action

Then log out from iTunes connect and re-log in to show the new bundle id available.

Comment: So how about the second question, are there any fixed formats of a bundle id suffix? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's recommended by Apple to use the format: _com.domainname.appname_.
This string must match the Bundle Identifier in your project.

Comment: ``Then log out from iTunes connect and re-log in to show the new bundle id available.`` You saved my life!

Comment: @pete link works - you need to be logged in to your developer account