# How to get iTunes Connect to recognise a new Bundle ID

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I’m having trouble getting iTunes Connect to recognise a new Bundle ID. On the [iTunes Connect Developer Help page](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev2cd126805), in step 4 it says

> Bundle ID shows two options: *Choose* and *Xcode: iOS Wildcard AppID -*
>   *

This is the step I'm missing. I found no way to enter the app Bundle ID *as shown here*.

[image]

Underneath the text window I clicked the link in *Register a new Bundle ID on the Developer Portal* which creates the new certificate. I then *Build* for a *Generic iOS Device* and when I tried to validate the certificate  got this message

> iTunes Store operation failed. This bundle is invalid. The value for
>   key CFBundleShortVersionString [1.0] in the Info.plist file must
>   contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version
>   [1.0].

Obviously it is invalid as I never got past step 4 to complete the form for the first app record. I tried [logging out of iTunes Connect and logging in again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24467859/2348597) and yes, the certificate was there (highlighted). The form just doesn't recognise it (and yes, I tried the other one).

Has anyone else seen this ?

[image]

Comment: Please paste a screenshot showing the AppID (with bundleID) from your app in developer.apple.com and from the dialog to create a new app in itunesconnect .

Comment: Fabio, as requested.

Comment: I recommend you to create an explicit AppID for your app. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html)
Then you can select this new AppID in iTunesConnect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> iTunes Store operation failed. This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [1.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [1.0].

I had same problem when i submitted my app second build with version number "1.0". In next build, I forgot to change version number from "1.0" to "1.1" and got this error.

I changed my new version to be "1.1" and the submission worked.

Comment: Abhishek, that would be right for the next version. Mine is a new app

Comment: I've accepted it as the correct answer even though unfortunately it won't fix my current problem which was caused by deleting the previous version.